# Show different View to Admin and User

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wish to show a different View form my Action method to an Admin and User:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CreateIssue issue = new CreateIssue();
    if (user.SupportAdmin)
    {
        return View("Admin/Create", issue);
    }

    return View(issue);
}
```

Then my Views look like this:

```
@model myApp.Models.CreateIssue
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IT HelpDesk - Create a new Issue";
}

@Html.Partial("_Create")
```

I have put the content inside a Partial called `_Create` as most of the content is the same, but I want to add an additional input to the Admin view which will sit in the middle of my `_Create` partial view. I'm not sure how to go about this, I did try to render a `section` in my Admin create view which is called inside the partial but they're only allowed on the `_Layout` page I think?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use an if statement?

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    @*Put input here*@
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the Role Provider. And I don't like to contain logic in my views